# `Dynamically populate a dropdown menu using strings from a textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want this coded in jquery preferably but normally, javascript is still fine by me.

The question is this: 
I have a textarea and a dropdown menu on thesame page. 
I can fill in text into the textarea by typing it or pasting it. The textarea on eachline contain emails and names seperated by comma.: Eg

> *email1@xyz.com, Richards Dough*
>
> *email2@abc.com*
>
> *EmilY34@yahoo.com   , Emily Whites*
>
> *Juniorpope4u@gmail.com ,  Junior*
>
> *Mike87@yahoo.co.uk,*
>
> *Ademola45thus@gmail.com, Ademola Erickson*

etc
(notice the comma can be anywhere or even absent)
I want the dropdown menu to automatically be filled with the values of domain names of emails found on the textarea.
NOTE: There should NOT be duplicate listing in the dropdown and the listing should be alphabetically arranged in the dropdown
In my example, the dropdown will be be populated as below:

> *ALL*
>
> *abc.com*
>
> *gmail.com*
>
> *xyz.com*
>
> *yahoo.com*
>
> *yahoo.co.uk*

Default selected dropdown item has a value of ***ALL***.
Please I know how to do this in php but have no clue about using javascript or jquery. Plus php have to refresh page to work but javascript wouldn't need page reloading

Comment: want me to write a invoice for that too??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-split by comma and newline

-loop through each splited string

- check whether it has @ symbol
- Find the domain and return

-display it in the select box

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="emails" onkeyup="finddomain();">
email1@xyz.com, Richards Dough    
email2@abc.com   
EmilY34@yahoo.com   , Emily Whites    
Juniorpope4u@gmail.com ,  Junior    
Mike87@yahoo.co.uk,    
Ademola45thus@gmail.com, Ademola Erickson
</textarea>

<select id="add_domain" name="add_domain">


</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function extractDomain(url) {   
    var ind=url.indexOf("@");
    if (ind > 0)
    {
    var domain = url.substr((ind+1));
    return domain;
    }
    else
    return '';
}

function finddomain()
{
// You can do the below parts on javascript event
data = document.getElementById('emails').value;
var arr = data.split(/[\n,]+/); //data.split('\n');
var arrayLength = arr.length;

var sel = document.getElementById("add_domain");

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var domain = extractDomain(arr[i].trim());

    if (domain != '' && $("#add_domain option[value='"+domain+"']").length == 0)
    {
    var option  = document.createElement("option");
    option.text  = domain;
    option.value = domain;

    sel.appendChild(option);    
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Below part is to extract domains for multiple events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emails').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
        // e.type is the type of event fired
        finddomain();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sir thanks for your codes, but it still shows irregularly when i type in data into the textarea. You can see the irregular results on this link: http://confirmia.in/testing/populate.php                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Try typing new line into the textarea and see the reults it provides on the dropdown.

Comment: I must say thank you for this answer and thank you @RRR too. These answers has helped me start understanding javascripts code. I have modified your answer with by removing onkeyup="finddomain();  from textarea and adding different triggers : like  $("#emails").focusout(function (e) { //trigger when textarea loses focus
    finddomain();
});
});

Comment: yeah you can remove the onkeyup and can use the block of codes above to trigger by changing the event to your preferred, also can do multiple events

Answer (score 1):

Hi Kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/pykmgyyt/5/ ...

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var arr= new Array();
  arr[0]="ALL"; //Setting fist element of the array to ALL

  $('.btnUpdate').on('click', function(){
  var newEmails=new Array();


  var newEmails=$('.taEmails').val().split(/[ ,\r\n]+/);  // get text area value and split text whenever jq encounters comma, space or newline and storing it into an array

  /* Travese through newEMails array and push string which contains '@' in to arr array */
  $.each(newEmails, function(i){
    if (newEmails[i].indexOf('@') > -1){
          arr.push(newEmails[i].substring(newEmails[i].indexOf("@") + 1)); /* Get only the domain names*/
        console.log(newEmails[i]);
    }

  });


  // check for duplicates
  var result = [];
  $.each(arr, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  arr= result;



        $('.ddEmails').empty(); // Empty dropdown
      arr.sort(); // sort array
      /*Append new array*/
   $.each(arr, function(i){
    $('.ddEmails').append("<option>"+arr[i]+"</option>");
    //console.log(arr[i]);
   }); /// arr each   
  }); //  click
});
```

Comment: your code is good , but honestly I would love it to populate the dropdown automatically without having to click the "Update" button. Thank you for your response

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You kicked started my learning of javascript. You are awesome